# how to recover a thin lv snapshot?

Tags: linux, lvm, kvm, snapshot

i managed to create a snapshot from my thin lv

how can i recover it ?

```
root@ghv214:/dev/ghv214-vg# lvs
  LV            VG        Attr       LSize  Pool          Origin     Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  Snap_Test     ghv214-vg Vwi---tz-k 40.00g Thin_LVM_Test Thin_LVM_V                                        
  Thin_LVM_Test ghv214-vg twi-aotz-- 40.00g                          50.00  16.60                           
  Thin_LVM_V    ghv214-vg Vwi-a-tz-- 40.00g Thin_LVM_Test            50.00                                  
  kvm_pool      ghv214-vg -wi-ao----  2.69t                                                                 
  root          ghv214-vg -wi-ao---- 59.60g                                                                 
  swap          ghv214-vg -wi-ao---- 29.80g                                                                 
  var           ghv214-vg -wi-ao---- 29.80g
```

*** Snap_Test ***
is my snapshot from 'Thin_LVM_V'
i tried to use `lvconvert --mergesnapshot`
but i didnt worked out.

```
 root@ghv214:/dev/ghv214-vg#  lvconvert --mergesnapshot /dev/ghv214-vg/Snap_Test
  Command on LV ghv214-vg/Snap_Test does not accept LV type thin.
  Command not permitted on LV ghv214-vg/Snap_Test.
```

can any one help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody found any solution, I have finally found the answer to my question.

We need to use the following command:

`lvconvert --mergethin <path_to_thin_lv_snapshot>`

Correct output will be:

`Volume <vg_gourp/snapshot_name> replaced origin <vg_group/thin_lv>`.

This will replace the snapshot with the thin lv volume.